# Can't remove a todo in react / redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm new and i'm trying to learn react and redux, I was trying to do this simple user list / todo list, I can add list items but I can't remove them with the remove in the reducer, if i click on the button it deletes all the array and the log of payload returns undefined, can someone help me? thanks all for the help!

STORE

```
   import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userState } from "./UsersState";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users: userState.reducer,
});

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
```

REDUCER

```
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userState = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => [...state, action.payload],
    remove: (state, action) =>
      state.filter((user, index) => user.id !== action.payload),
    clear: (state, action) => [],
    log: (state, action) => console.log(state),
  },
});
```

RENDER

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./Store";
import { add, remove, clear, userState } from "./UsersState";

export function UsersList() {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function addUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(userState.actions.add(event.target.elements.username.value));
    dispatch(userState.actions.log());
  }
  function removeUser() {
    dispatch(userState.actions.remove());
  }

  function clearList() {
    dispatch(userState.actions.clear());
    console.log(store.getState());
  }

  function logState() {
    dispatch(userState.actions.log());
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="ul">
        {users.map((user, index) => (
          <div className="list-element" key={index + 1}>
            <li key={index}>{user}</li>
            <button onClick={removeUser} type="submit">
              remove
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={addUser}>
        <input name="username" type="text" />
        Insert name
        <button type="submit">Add user</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={clearList}>Clear list</button>
      <button onClick={logState}>Log state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, update the component like following (I commented on the place of change)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./Store";
import { add, remove, clear, userState } from "./UsersState";
// make sure to export these actions from the reducer file

export function UsersList() {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function addUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(userState.actions.add(event.target.elements.username.value));
    dispatch(userState.actions.log());
  }
  function removeUser() {
    dispatch(userState.actions.remove());
  }

  function clearList() {
    dispatch(userState.actions.clear());
    console.log(store.getState());
  }

  function logState() {
    dispatch(userState.actions.log());
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="ul">
        {users.map((user, index) => (
          <div className="list-element" key={index + 1}>
            <li key={index}>{user}</li>
            {/* you can directly dispatch the remove function*/}
            {/* no need this button to be type="button"*/}
            {/* change here */}
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(remove(user))}>
              remove
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={addUser}>
        <input name="username" type="text" />
        Insert name
        <button>Add user</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={clearList}>Clear list</button>
      <button onClick={logState}>Log state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You needed to pass user in the action and dispatch it, hope it helps!

For the reducer file, you have to export the actions also

```js
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userState = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => [...state, action.payload],
    remove: (state, action) =>
      // need to redefine the state, forgot this part
      // change here
      state = state.filter((user, index) => user !== action.payload),
    clear: (state, action) => [],
    log: (state, action) => console.log(state),
  },
});

export const {add, remove, clear, log} = userState.actions;
export default userState.reducer;
```

Comment: Thanks for the informations, really, but I tried to paste your code but it continues to delete all the list instead of deleting only the selected item

Comment: I solved it passing the index ( <button onClick={() => dispatch(remove(index))}>) and on the reducer:  state.filter((user, index) =>index !== action.payload),

Comment: I updated the reducer file, can you check? I think the problem was , you were not setting the state after filtering. Check the updated reducer file. Thanks
Let me know if it worked!

Comment: nope, if i pass the user.id it continues deleting the entire array, with index passed and index !== action.payload it works, still dunno why xD, but i really thank you for the advice cause it helped me

Comment: Okay. Can you share this project's repo.... better to have a broader view on this. May be this is a small silly bug somewhere.

Comment: okay i updated the files! Can you check the changes, you need to make changes where there are comment "change here"

Comment: Ok now it works but with user instead of index when I delete the item list it deletes all the items with that name, if I put index on the filter and on the dispatch it works correctly, thanks again very helpful, I didn't know I could dispatch it directly and pass a parameter

Comment: Okay great! It didn't work before because of data format.  there was no user.id, but you were filtering based on it.